# C#, Excel, OleDB, Insert statement not working

Tags: c#, excel, insert, oledb

I haven't found anyone with a similar problem so I'm asking for help. I wrote a simple program that is supposed to read data from an Excel spreadsheet(A) and after doing some calculations will insert computed data into a different spreadsheet(B).

I can execute SELECT commands without any problems but when I execute an INSERT command with ExecuteNonQuery it returns 1(meaning 1 row affected) and yet nothing is inserted into the spreadsheet.

I open the file without the Imex parameter in the connection string. I even tried adding this parameter but got an exception.

the insert statement is(example):

```
Insert into [Test$](F3,F4,F5,F6,F9,F10,F11,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21,F22,F23,F24,F25,F26) values('1','1','1','2010-07-12','PR','C','P','1','R','OR',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
```

**EDIT**

It seems like the source of the problem is the spreadsheet itself. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you pls provide the exception you are getting?

Comment: With Imex=1 I got "Operation must use an updateable query."

Comment: Do you have these field names F3, F4 etc in your excel sheet? Try inserting one or two values first... then it may be easy for you to identify the problem...

Comment: I don't use headers thus the names are automatically set this way.

Comment: Add headers, then try whether it works...

Comment: Added headers, limited the query to just one field and still nothing - the query executes without error but nothing changes

Comment: I know that's super old, but bugs never age, so i'll write it here in case someone need: if you need to write on an existing sheet, and ExecuteNonQuery is returning 1 but you can't see anything, try to check the bottom of the file, because it's probably writing there for no reason...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following link:

It has a very simple code and it works fine for me:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-insert.htm

Comment: OK, to i used the code provided and created an empty Excel file to write to and it worked. So probably something is wrong with my original file, but what could be wrong? I have to write to that file - cannot create a new one. Can Chcecking Compatibility have any impact?

Comment: Is your excel sheet xls or xlsx? Isn t your file empty?

Comment: My Excel sheet is xls, it is empty but has certain formatting settings that have to be saved. All it contains are the headers right now(i've added them).

Comment: What kind of formatting do you have? Are you sure the text colour is not white???

Comment: LOL, I'm 100% positive the text is not white. The formatting settings set the alignment of text, the font and it's size - not the color

Comment: You may create a new file and test with the insert query and see, then may add formatting...